# Xcode Error launching remote program

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I've seen this all over the place on stack overflow, but everyone else's solution doesn't work for me. Help! Please!

I'm trying to test my app on my iPhone, it's run perfectly fine up until I updated Xcode and the iOS (I've also been on v4 though). I can't get it to sync the app over at all. I've tried dumping this file/folder, dumping caches, quitting relaunching Xcode, Rebooting the Computer, Restarting the phone, everything I can think of to no avail. Any Ideas?

```
Error launching remote program: No such file or directory
(/Users/andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BTC_Exchange-drzeigaqfnjtatglpppiwxmscsoj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BTC Exchange.app/BTC Exchange).
```

And the file does exist, there are no permissions issues from what I can tell and I ran a whole disk permissions check too.

Comment: BTW, I am running 10.7 GM build with the latest version of Xcode. The issue has always occurred after updating Xcode.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go here: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and clear out all the old builds.  It'll work again without having to do the project renaming etc.

Comment: It's important to restart XCode after deleting the DerivedData directory

Comment: BTW, I got so annoyed with this issue, I wrote an app to solve the problem: http://watchdogforxcode.com/ The app monitors and clears the DerivedData for you.

Answer (score 8):

Try to clear  ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and RESTART Xcode.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the exact same issue as you. I tried everything you did, and just like you *none* of those solutions worked for me. Just now I was finally able to get it to work (whew). Here is how I did it:

1. Rename your project to anything different. Do this in Xcode 4 by **slowly** double clicking on the project name in the Project Navigator.
2. Go to your project info.plist. Change the bundle identifier to match the new project name. Also change the bundle name just to be safe...
3. Do a <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> to clean the project. Then run!

That worked for me. Good luck.

Comment: Genius.. I followed the steps, and then reverted back everything, and it worked!!

Comment: Yes! Great! Finally my app on iOS6 beta. It worked only after I renamed the project! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

**Go : ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData**

**Clear user Data**

**Clean the Project**

**Quit the xcode(make sure you quite. Look at the picture)**

```
   ![Quit xCode][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me, doing Product -> Clean then restarting XCode worked.

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of DerivedData and restarting Xcode worked.

It was the suggestion of Dave Wood Feb 17 at 8:20

> "Try to clear ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and RESTART
>   Xcode."

In my case, I had about 7 different "DerivedData"s, which I found by doing a search of DerivedData in finder and deleting them all, closing Xcode, and rebooting.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

This usually happens when you run multiple projects which have stored their data at `derived data`, and therefore Xcode becomes a mess sometimes for different reasons, usually indexing a project to two different **Workspaces**

## Solution

Follow these steps to get out of the mess :

1. Quit Xcode if it is opened
2. Go to derived data's folder located at ***~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData***
3. Delete everything on that folder (Also empty the trash)
4. Open up Xcode and do a **Product Clean** by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>
5. Run your project and everything will be back to normal

## Background

*With Xcode 4 came the concept of a workspace that allows multiple projects to be grouped together. Each workspace gets a unique set of symbol indexes, build products, window layouts, etc., otherwise referred to by Xcode as derived data*

Answer (score 0):

I would use the normal Xcode for the non-GM release and also the non-GM iPhone OS. Also I would try to reboot your device if you haven't tried that already. Make sure all the software on your computer is updated too.
I am using all of the latest stuff and I have no issues on iOS 5.

Answer (score 0):

Please quit the xcode and then start it works fine with me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the answers above worked for me, i've decided to share what i've found out.

My problem was the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities values on the Info.plist file. I added they key gps when what I needed was location-services, since my app is supposed to work not only for iPhone, but for iPod touch as well. When I tried to debug it on the Simulator it all ran just fine, but on the iPod touch that I use for debugging I kept getting that stupid message.

Hope my answer helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Such problems happens for me when I tried to run application on IPhone 3g using XCode 4.4.1 (4F1003). Gabriel's solution help me find out what is wrong - in `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` was `"armv7"` value, I changed it to `"armv6"` and error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to put my own solution here since this has been happening to me non-stop!

- close xcode
- delete the derived data folder
- unplug and restart the device
- then re-open xcode and power on and reconnect the device

that has been working for me. These steps individually have never worked for me so I just do them all.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same error and while I don't have any new solution to add, I would like to point out in the path above, and in the path I am seeing in my own case, there is a malformed file string:

/Users/{user}/..../appname.app**/appname**

This is the real problem.  And there is no such entry in any project file

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem on Xcode 4.4.1, with an old iPod 3G running iOS 4.2.1.

My application requires iMessage, so I had added a UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities entry 'sms' to the app-Info.plist.

I updated my app code to check the device for the SMS class functionality (MFMessageComposeViewController) before executing it, and I removed the 'sms' key. So, when testing my code on older devices, to see if it worked, I stumbled onto this error one time when I re-added the app-Info.plist 'sms' key.

Now get this: With my app on an older device (no 'sms' key), I can add or remove the 'sms' key and Xcode has no problem cleaning/building/running; but if I delete the app from the device and then clean/build/run, Xcode complains about the directory not existing (and it's actually there), until I remove the pesky 'sms' key.

I hope this makes sense and can help somebody.